# Calculating end position from existing position, velocity, deceleration and time

Tags: inertia, algorithms

I am writing a piece of software where the user can drag an element only on the x axis. When the user lets go of the drag while the item is in motion I can determine the x velocity and the current x position of the element.

I cannot figure out what formula I should use to calculate the x endpoint of the element using its velocity, current position and a deceleration constant. What formula should I be using?

Comment: When you write a question, try to be as clear as possible. in its present formulation, your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation should be good for your purposes: vf^2 = vi^2 + 2ad

The final velocity will obviously be zero, so then you just solve this equation for d:

vi^2 + 2ad = 0, plugging in the object's current velocity and deceleration constant.

Once you have the value for d, add this to the object's current position. That is the x endpoint.

Comment: As someone new to understanding formulas thank you for the easy to read format! But I am struggling to understand the symbols used in the formula though, I am assuming v = velocity and d = distance but I am not confident with the others (f, i and d).

Comment: v = velocity and d = displacement (since they are both vectors, a negative value for them means going in the negative direction). vf is final velocity, vi is initial velocity, and a is acceleration (a vector as well, which is negative due to deceleration).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

$$ x = x_{0} + v_{0}t - \frac{1}{2}kt² $$ where **k** is the magnitude of your deceleration constant. Of course, you will need to choose the time that's associated with such x endpoint.

Instead, if you want to know where is the maximum **x** the particle will go after being decelerated until its speed goes to 0, you can use Torricelli's formula:

$$ v^{2} = v_{0}^{2} - 2k(x - x_{0})$$

$$ 0 = v_{0}^{2} - 2k(x - x_{0}) $$
$$ 2k(x - x_{0}) = v_{0}^{2}$$
$$ \therefore x = x_{0} + \frac{v_{0}^{2}}{2k}$$